# CSS position fixed however same place in all screen res

Tags: html, css

Im adding a "floating" (fixed) box however i need it in the same position no matter what the screen res is. So when you scroll down the screen it stays at the exact position on the moniter (like facebook chat kinda thing, i have a div like this already however i just set it to 100% and for this i need some exact positionings)

At the moment in the css file i have:

```
.userAccOvervw{
    position:fixed;
    border: 1px solid #73a7f0;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    padding: 5px 14px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

However this changes depending upon the screen res, i have tried floating it next to various  so float right (to the left of a div) and that didnt work :/

If anyone has any advice I would be most grateful :-)

Comment: I believe your answer is more towards a mixture of position: absolute and Javascript. Using Javascript to find the current scroll amount, then setting the top and left style attributes to the scroll plus your offset. However, the most effective way to do this using Javascript without lags or anything of the such is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change position to absolute and specify a top and left?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Sorry just edited out my comment realised my stupidness! Haha give me 1 min ;)

Comment: You need something like this http://blog.echoenduring.com/2010/11/15/freebie-contained-sticky-scroll-jquery-plugin/.

Comment: @elclanrs that looks nice! I will try that some time! And thanks Andrew :-) it works

Comment: @elclanrs That is complete overkill. CSS fixed positioning is simpler and gives a better result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're actually looking for `position: absolute;`, not `position: fixed;`

Comment: Hey, I tried that before (and just now) the div wont stay positioned like when you scroll down it doesnt stay in its position

Answer (score 0):

A lot like `position:absolute`, fixed positioning requires you to specify `top` and `left` values. Try something like this:

```
.userAccOvervw{
    position:fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 14px;

    /* removed fancy CSS3 stuff for clarity */
}
```